# How to avoid redirect from subdomain in htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I am currently using this in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But it has the unfortunate effect of redirecting every call to the mobile site (m.example.com) to the main page. How do I make an exception to m.example.com? I don't know how to setup RewriteRule correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

And make sure to clear your browser cache.